# Single finger scrolling panes - how?

Tags: webkit, jquery-mobile

See here:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/ (click/tap on "Touch Events")

The pane that explains the touch events available, you can drag w/ one finger on an iPad or iPhone, and even on the desktop you can use the mouse to drag/scroll as well. How does this work?! I need to be able to do this without Sensa Touch (we're using jQuery Mobile).

Answer (score 0):

I used iScroll4 and it worked fairly well.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

If you are using jQuery Mobile, you may want to try out their experimental "Scroll View."  I haven't ran across a reason to try it yet but it does look promising.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/

Comment: iScroll is a bit quirky. I was looking for a way to do this without plugins. Surely there's a way..